# How to set ModelKeyPath in InterfaceBuilder to be the opposite of a BOOL property

Tags: cocoa, menu, interface-builder, hidden, kvc

I am setting few menu items to enabled and/or hidden and it’s all based on one bool property. I do the set up with bindings and use the Model Key Path field. I would like to set up the opposite bool value of that property in some cases and I am not sure how to do that. I’ve tried using !boolProperty, but Xcode gives me an error that my class is not KVC compliant with !boolProperty.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From the *Value Transformer* drop down menu in the bindings select *NSNegateBoolean*. That'll do the trick.

[image: NSNegateBoolean Value Transformer]